# socket.timeout on telegram bot.polling()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, bots, telegram

When I leave my program running for a few hours and then send a message to the bot it doesn't reply and after a while it generates the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1322, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 447, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botTest.py", line 28, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 617, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 676, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 639, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 130, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 82, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "botTest.py", line 25, in echo_message
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 2147, in reply_to
    return self.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 919, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 257, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 139, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
```

From what I understand the problem lies in the requests made by bot.polling ().

I also tried with the example file echo_bot.py but the problem is the same.
I tried different solutions:

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=30)
```

and

```
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(15)
```

Unfortunately all with the same problem. At first it works correctly and then after a few hours it stops responding.

This is sample code

```
import telebot

API_TOKEN = 'API_TOKEN'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi there, I am EchoBot.")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


bot.polling()
```

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by replacing `bot.polling()` with:

```
bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout = 5)
```

However, this can cause (not everyone) a loss of messages (apparently only at the beginning, after a few days the problem seems to disappear by itself).

***As you can see I have sent 5 messages and there have been only 3 replies***

[image]

I will update this answer as soon as I find a solution.
The problem however is explained here:

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/1259

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os, sys
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ReadTimeout

try:
    bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout=5)
except (ConnectionError, ReadTimeout) as e:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)
else:
    bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout=5)
```

that works for me i just restart the script lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, some people use the web hook method and actually it is a best and proper solution. Anyway in my case I tried this idea before learning web hook, and it helped me to keep bot running and keep trying to reconnect every time it's disconnected. It's easy and fun)

```
import telebot,time

if __name__=='__main__':
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
bot.infinity_polling(True)
```

Comment: No already tried and gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

This option helped me

```
while True:
try:
    asyncio.run(bot.polling(non_stop=True, interval=1, timeout=0))
except:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout to `90 seconds` and add a try-catch block to handle the exception as follows:

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=90)
    except Exception as e:
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), e)
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

Comment: Так происходит потому что, сервера телеграмм не справляются с нагрузкой в пике

Answer (score 0):

first, check if you are able or not open https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

if not:
change the network then try